# How to save a remote image using the WebBrowser

Tags: c#, image, browser

Used a variety of methods, related to capture, convert the image file in memory and then exiled to read, do not know if there are other good ways

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is that you're asking here. What Web Images collection are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, that's clear, has been amended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the src attribute of the image tag by going through the WebBrowser DOM and then manually re-request it with System.Net.HttpWebRequest. [Example of downloading image with HttpWebRequest](http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Download-Image-from-URL.html)